# Can't use own packages in remote_api

Tags: google-app-engine

I've enabled remote_api and can import and use sdk libraries like google.appengine.ext.db but cannot import the app's own packages like models.py

I had run the remote_api script with this command from within the root directory of the app (containing app.yaml)

```
python /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py -s app-id.appspot.com
```

Comment: From which directory do you run it? You should run it from your project`s directory. Does `sys.path` contain the directory of you project?

Comment: When I do sys.path I get a list of paths either from the python dir or from the GAE dir, none of them are related to my project dir. However I am running the remote_api from within the project's root folder.

Answer (score 2):

Your app dir is not on sys.path. You can add it in your session:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

or set it in your shell:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
```